# Triggers performance based on system timings

Tags: mysql

My question might sound stupid but i would be glad if someone answers to this:)

when we set a trigger which performs an action like now(), curdate(), curtime() on dependency of systems date and time, does it consider the change in time that happens before the deletion or update,
 example - i have a trigger set today(6-11-2012) at 5 pm i have to delete a set of rows tomorrow i.e on 7-11-2012 at 5 pm. in this time gap i change the timings or date of my system, now does the trigger consider the newly changed date and time for deleting the rows.

Comment: check the timezone of mysql server first & then do as per that timezone.

Comment: You wrote "trigger." Do you, perhaps, mean "event?"  Events are the MySQL instructions that run automatically at a particular time.